# Using sortedcontainers in Python to emulate BST

Tags: python, sortedcollection, sortedcontainers

I see some people recommending using `SortedContainers` as a drop in for some tree structures like Binary Trees like this [reddit](https://amp.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/9allgh/wheres_pythons_damn_binary_search_tree/&ampcf=1) thread. The documentation for [SortedContainers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) mentions how it's more space efficient than typical implementations of Binary Trees

Having said that, I don't actually see anyone talk about HOW to use it as such and I'd greatly appreciate if someone had a reference for how to emulate a BST or something of the like using Sortedcontainers or SortedCollection

Comment: Wasn't asking how to use it, was asking how to emulate X via `SortedContainers`. A better comment would have been "It's implemented as X under the hood, so you just need to use it instead of trying to emulate X"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: In my use case, I didn't need to "Use sortedcontainers to emulate Tree structure X" because it IS tree structure X under the hood